# Reading all the csv files with Pandas inside a folder Location Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, class

How would I be able to have to make a python script that can read all the csv files in a folder and dynamically assign variable names to it. The variable names for the datasets will be of the name of the csv files. Example the csv file allocated at the specified `folder_location` FTX_BTCUSD.csv will be named `FTX_BTCUSD` as a variable. Pandas will be used to read the csv files using `pd.read_csv()`. How would I be able to modify the function below to get the expected output.

```
import pandas as pd 

folder_location = 'C:\\Users\\local\\datasets'

def pandas_datasets():
    data= pd.read_csv(**dataset location**, low_memory=False)
    return data
```

Folder csv files
[image]

Contents of FTX_BTCUSD.csv

```
unix,date,symbol,open,high,low,close,Volume,Volume USD
1644430740000.0,2022-02-09 18:19:00,BTC/USD,44079.0,44096.0,44076.0,44088.0,0.8561232648339684,37744.7625
1644430680000.0,2022-02-09 18:18:00,BTC/USD,44069.0,44079.0,44055.0,44079.0,3.9830549127702537,175569.0775
1644430620000.0,2022-02-09 18:17:00,BTC/USD,44074.0,44079.0,44055.0,44069.0,7.00427581973723,308671.4311
1644430560000.0,2022-02-09 18:16:00,BTC/USD,44077.0,44078.0,44056.0,44074.0,4.813299484957118,212141.3615
1644430500000.0,2022-02-09 18:15:00,BTC/USD,44033.0,44078.0,44033.0,44077.0,8.620666560791342,379973.12
```

Contents of Binance_BTCUSD.csv

```
Unix Timestamp,Date,Symbol,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Volume USDT,tradecount
1625531700000,2021-07-06 00:35:00,BTC/USDT,34039.99000000,34053.86000000,34023.50000000,34053.86000000,14.84518900,505301.96192877,271
1625531640000,2021-07-06 00:34:00,BTC/USDT,34025.88000000,34049.42000000,34020.11000000,34039.99000000,22.81862800,776568.09766191,404
1625531580000,2021-07-06 00:33:00,BTC/USDT,34050.32000000,34062.77000000,34017.25000000,34025.89000000,16.08606300,547582.96995436,418
1625531520000,2021-07-06 00:32:00,BTC/USDT,34014.66000000,34058.40000000,34001.64000000,34058.39000000,26.11695400,888581.95856325,593
```

Comment: Better to have a dictionary with the keys as the file names and values as the contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create variables through `globals()` althought this is **not** recommended. It is much better to use a dictionary with the keys as the file names.

Try:

```
import os
data = dict()
for file in os.listdir(folder_location):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        data[file.replace(".csv","")] = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(folder_location, file))
```

If you absolutlely *must* create dynamic variables with the file names, use the below instead:

```
import os
for file in os.listdir(folder_location):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        globals()[file.replace(".csv","")] = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(folder_location, file))
```